# Patrick Stewart film with naked aliens who turn people into zombies

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Looking for identification for a film I haven't seen in a long, long time (maybe 2 decades ago).

The film is in colour but I remember it being quite dark, and it was made a while ago, maybe in the 70s.  It was set during that time in England and featured naked human-looking aliens going around London (or some other British city) turning people into zombie like things.

The only actor I can remember in the film is Patrick Stewart.  The only other person I can picture was one of the aliens who was an attractive female who was always naked.  I also have vague memories of a large tower of light or a beam of light where the aliens came from or lived in.

The film stood out to me because it was a sci-fi set in England, which was a rare thing at the time I saw it.

Comment: why the vote to close?

Comment: Maybe someone freaked out by naked zombifying aliens, and now they can't sleep at night because of you.

Comment: Possibly because you can simply look at the filmography of this actor.

Comment: I immediately thought of the scene in 'Extras' where he's describing a film pitch to Ricky Gervais, and the scenes keep ending with the characters clothes falling off.

Comment: @AJ "Simply"? Stewart has been in a LOT of movies, and the correct title may not jump out.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson There are more than 50 movies of him and X Men and Star Trek are eliminated as OP described. OP also said that it was made in 70s, thus eliminating more movies and leaving only a few. And I suppose now it is *simple* to find out.

Comment: @AJ I thought the film came out in the 70s, and the film actually came out in the 80s, so it might not been as easy as you make out - plus i thought there were zombies and people here are talking about vampires - but you are right, with research I could have worked this all out for myself - but where do we draw the line? at what point do we say "well they could have worked that out for themselves"? - which is surely true for all of the questions on this site... perhaps https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask should have something that says "do your research on IMDB before asking"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hot naked female alien draining **Lifeforce** from people, with Patrick Stewart in it?

Only one candidate -

[IMDB - Lifeforce (1985)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089489/)

Actress Mathilda May, with almost no wardrobe budget that was discernible, played the alien in question.

Comment: Beat me to it by about 30 seconds. ;-)

Comment: @BrettFromLA - I was about 17 when that movie came out.  It's burned into my memory.

Comment: @Jimmery - Fairly certain Patrick Stewart only made one naked alien vampire zombie-maker film  :D

Comment: Fair warning: the image gallery on that IMDB page has a couple of movie posters where Mathilda May is displayed in full frontal nudity. Keep that in mind in case you're thinking about visiting the page, especially from work.

Answer (score 7):

The 1985 film Lifeforce had Stewart as Dr. Armstrong. It was about alien vampires that made zombies in London.

Much like Alien Vampires, Patrick Stewart also hasn't aged since 1985.

Comment: Sadly, in the very few recent years, he actually has appeared to start picking up some years.   Unless of course that's just what he wants everyone to think.   He is quite a skilled actor after all.